# Customising destruction procedure in std::vector::erase()

Tags: c++

When I call the erase function on a vector of type 'T', then the destructor of the elements following the range on which I've called the erase() is called. Is there a way to customize this behavior? How can I ensure that the destructors of those elements which are being erased are called?

**Sample Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum type {
    TYPE_DEFAULT,
    TYPE0,
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
    TYPE3,
    TYPE4,
};

char str[][13] = {"TYPE_DEFAULT","TYPE0","TYPE1","TYPE2","TYPE3","TYPE4"};

struct temp {
    type objType;

    void printInfo() const {
        std::cout << "\nthis-->" << this;
        std::cout << "\nType-->" << str[objType]<<"\n";
    }

    temp() {
        objType = type::TYPE_DEFAULT;
        std::cout << "\n**Default Constructor**";
        printInfo();
    }

    temp(const temp& obj) = default;

    temp& operator=(const temp& obj) {
        std::cout << "\n**operator=**";
        objType = obj.objType;
        printInfo();
        return *this;
    }

    ~temp() {
        std::cout << "\n**Destructor**";
        this->printInfo();
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {

    std::vector<temp> vec;
    vec.resize(5);

    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        vec[i].objType = (type)(i+1);
    }

    std::cout <<"\nPrinting vector before erase. Size->" << vec.size()<< "\n";

    for (const auto& x : vec) {
        x.printInfo();
    }

    int start = 0;
    int end = 2;
    std::cout << "\nGoing to call erase for vec[" << start << ","<< end << ")\n";

    vec.erase(vec.begin() + start, vec.begin() + end);

    std::cout << "\nErase has been invoked\n";

    std::cout << "\nPrinting vector Info after erase. Size->"<<vec.size() << "\n";

    for (const auto& x : vec)
        x.printInfo();

}
```

**Output**

```
**Default Constructor**
this-->0xf9c010
Type-->TYPE_DEFAULT

**Default Constructor**
this-->0xf9c014
Type-->TYPE_DEFAULT

**Default Constructor**
this-->0xf9c018
Type-->TYPE_DEFAULT

**Default Constructor**
this-->0xf9c01c
Type-->TYPE_DEFAULT

**Default Constructor**
this-->0xf9c020
Type-->TYPE_DEFAULT

Printing vector before erase. Size->5

this-->0xf9c010
Type-->TYPE0

this-->0xf9c014
Type-->TYPE1

this-->0xf9c018
Type-->TYPE2

this-->0xf9c01c
Type-->TYPE3

this-->0xf9c020
Type-->TYPE4

Going to call erase for vec[0,2)

**operator=**
this-->0xf9c010
Type-->TYPE2

**operator=**
this-->0xf9c014
Type-->TYPE3

**operator=**
this-->0xf9c018
Type-->TYPE4

**Destructor**
this-->0xf9c01c
Type-->TYPE3


**Destructor**
this-->0xf9c020
Type-->TYPE4


Erase has been invoked

Printing vector Info after erase. Size->3

this-->0xf9c010
Type-->TYPE2

this-->0xf9c014
Type-->TYPE3

this-->0xf9c018
Type-->TYPE4

**Destructor**
this-->0xf9c010
Type-->TYPE2


**Destructor**
this-->0xf9c014
Type-->TYPE3


**Destructor**
this-->0xf9c018
Type-->TYPE4
```

**Program Description**

In the above program, I have a vector(size 5) of a structure named `temp`. When I call `erase` on range [0,2), destructors of last 2 elements are called. What do I need to do to call the destructors of first 2 elements instead?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want those specific objects to be destructed, or just curiosity?

Comment: The first two elements (the erased ones) are overwritten by the assignment operator when moving/copying later elements of the vector to fill the gaps.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I was trying out a sample to test some ideas and this observation was surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with `std::vector`. Erasing will get rid of the items you want from the `std::vector`, but it may not destroy those specific objects.

If it is *absolutely necessary* to call the destructors of the first two elements, consider using a `deque` if you are going to only insert and erase at the back and the front, or a `std::forward_list` if you don't need random-access.

P.S. `std::vector` is horrible for insertions and erasures anywhere but the back, as it will have to move all the elements that are in front of the inserted/erased items.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to destroy the first two elements, as they are still valid after the erase, so it would be nonsensical to do so.  Their values have been overwritten by the assignments.  Perhaps what you actually want is to define a move-assignment operator that swaps the elements (a common way of implementing move assignment).  This will end up putting the data from those first two elements into the last two elements, so that is what the destructor will see when it destroys them.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class temp {
    static int uid;
    int id;
 public:
    temp() : id(++uid) {
        std::cout << "default ctor for temp #" << id << " at " << this << std::endl; }
    temp(temp &&a) : id(a.id) {
        std::cout << "moving temp #" << id << " from " << &a << " to " << this << std::endl; 
        a.id = -1; }
    ~temp() {
        if (id >= 0)
            std::cout << "destroying temp #" << id << " at " << this << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "destroying previously moved from temp at " << this << std::endl; }
    temp &operator=(temp &&a) {
        std::cout << "swapping temps #" << id << " and #" << a.id << " at " << this
                  << " and " << &a << std::endl;
        std::swap(id, a.id);
        return *this; }
    temp(const temp &) = delete;
    temp &operator=(const temp &) = delete;
};

int temp::uid = 0;

int main() {
    std::vector<temp>   v;
    std::cout << "resize vector to 5" << std::endl;
    v.resize(5);
    std::cout << "erase first two elements" << std::endl;
    v.erase(v.begin(), v.begin() + 2);
    std::cout << "end -- destroying vector" << std::endl;
}
```

which produces the output

```
resize vector to 5
default ctor for temp #1 at 0x5624ecff0280
default ctor for temp #2 at 0x5624ecff0284
default ctor for temp #3 at 0x5624ecff0288
default ctor for temp #4 at 0x5624ecff028c
default ctor for temp #5 at 0x5624ecff0290
erase first two elements
swapping temps #1 and #3 at 0x5624ecff0280 and 0x5624ecff0288
swapping temps #2 and #4 at 0x5624ecff0284 and 0x5624ecff028c
swapping temps #1 and #5 at 0x5624ecff0288 and 0x5624ecff0290
destroying temp #2 at 0x5624ecff028c
destroying temp #1 at 0x5624ecff0290
end -- destroying vector
destroying temp #3 at 0x5624ecff0280
destroying temp #4 at 0x5624ecff0284
destroying temp #5 at 0x5624ecff0288
```

You could also define the move-assign as destroying the destination then move (re)constructing it from the source.  When you have such a move ctor or move assignment, it is necessary to 'mark' the moved-from object in such a way that the destructor knows it does not really need to do anything.